# Overcome time issue with mysql and table data?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am building a game and users have money either in their hand or in a virtual bank so to say!

When transferring money from their hand and vice versa I am currently using,

```
if ($_POST['deposit'] > 0 && $_POST['deposit'] <= $user['shrapnel']) {
    $q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE items SET shrapnel = ?, bank = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $q -> execute(array($user['shrapnel'] - $_POST['deposit'], $user['bank'] + $_POST['deposit'], $user['id']));
}
```

Users can also set up trades and people can steal money off of each other, if a user steals enough money to de-validate the if statement at the exact time where php has validated the if statement for the current account but not completed the query, then the query will run but cause peoples money to go into negative numbers and all sorts of different confusion?!!

How can I get over this??

Answer (score 0):

You need to do all the testing and stuff in SQL.

First get the users details:

```
$deposit = $_POST['deposit'];
$user = $user['id']
.....
$q = $dbc->prepare('CALL DoMoneyStuff(?,?)'); //call to stored proc
$q->execute(array($deposit, $user));
$r = $dbc->prepare('SELECT h.shrapnel, b.amount FROM hand h
                    INNER JOIN Bank b ON (h.user_id = b.user_id)
                    WHERE h.user_id = ?');
$q->execute(array($user));
```

Use the following stored procedure to do your money stuff.
Because the stored proc runs on MySQL and all actions inside a stored proc run inside an implicit transaction, the money transfer either succeed completely or fail completely (it's now an atomic transaction).

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE DoMoneyStuff(Pdeposit DECIMAL(10,2)
                             ,Puser INTEGER)
BEGIN
  DECLARE Pshrapnel DECIMAL(10,2)

  SELECT Shrapnel INTO PShapnel FROM hand WHERE user_id = Puser LIMIT 1;
  IF Pshapnel >= Pdeposit THEN
    UPDATE hand SET Shrapnel = Shrapnel - Pdeposit WHERE user_id  Puser;
    UPDATE bank SET amount = amount + Pdeposit WHERE user_id = Puser;
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```